# андроид приложение не меняет значения в бд

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

Подскажите почему андроид приложение не меняет значения в бд(mysql).И выдает в логкэт [image]

класс mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
TextView textView;
DBHandler handler;
EditText editText;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
    handler=new DBHandler();

}
public void OnLoad(View view){
    MyTask t=new MyTask();
    t.execute();

}
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        handler.AddUser("Какашка" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}}
```

класс DBHandler

```
public class DBHandler extends Configs {
Connection dbConnection;
public Connection getDbConnection()throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String connection_string="jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbName;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dbConnection= DriverManager.getConnection(connection_string,dbUser,dbPass);
    return dbConnection;
}
public void AddUser(String user_name){
    String insert="INSERT INTO "+Const.USER_TABLE +"("+Const.USER_NAME+")"+"VALUES(?)";
    try { PreparedStatement prSt=getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
        prSt.setString(1,user_name);
        prSt.executeUpdate();}
    catch (SQLException e){
        Log.d("TAG", "AddUser: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();Log.d("TAG", "AddUser: C   "+e.getMessage());}
}}
```

класс const

```
public class Const {
public static final String USER_TABLE="user";
public static final String USER_ID="id_user";
public static final String USER_NAME="user_name";}
```

класс Сonfigs

```
public class Configs {
protected String dbHost="localhost";
protected String dbPort="3306";
protected String dbUser="root";
protected String dbPass="12345";
protected String dbName="users";}
```

[image: вот сама бд]

пороль-12345
логин-root

Comment: Я не уверен, но тут вроде пробелы надо добавить вокруг скобок. String insert="INSERT INTO "+Const.USER_TABLE +" ("+Const.USER_NAME+") "+"VALUES(?)";

Comment: В смысле добавить вокруг скобок? Не совсем понял

Comment: Понял сейчас попробую

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: а точки не должно быть между Const.USER_TABLE + "("+Const.USER_NAME+")" а вообще выведете в консоль переменую insert скопируйте значение и попробуйте выполнить в воркбенч

Comment: @AstendSanferion А как её выполнить в workbench

Comment: я не знаком с воркбенч, предполагаю можете нажать правой кнопкой мишки на вашу таблици и выбрать строчку Query (если есть) или вон с верху в меню вижу есть пункт Query. Вы же как то выполняете запрос SELECT * FROM...